# javascript regular expression to maximum of 12 decimal places and 2 floating places

Tags: javascript

I need to validate a number only using a regular expression to allow the only maximum of 12 decimal places and a maximum of 2 floating places. Here floating points are optional as well. I have already an expression as below to validate some other conditions.

```
onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\.\d]/g,'');"
```

I need to modify the above expression to validate my new requirement too. My attempt as below.

```
onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\.\d{1,12}{0,2}]/g,'');"
```

But it was not working. Sorry I have a little knowledge about regular expression. So can anyone help me to build this one to correct?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/BQKDkY/1

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the regex you're looking for:

```js
const regex = /^\d{1,12}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/;
console.log('123456789012.123', regex.test('123456789012.123'));
console.log('123456789012.12', regex.test('123456789012.12'));
console.log('123456789012.1', regex.test('123456789012.1'));
console.log('123456789012.', regex.test('123456789012.'));
console.log('123456789012', regex.test('123456789012'));
console.log('12345678901', regex.test('12345678901'));
```

Comment: When you use dot as a literal - you need to escape it.

Comment: Are the last two ones going to be false? But they are

Comment: @Leonid Click on "Run Code snippet button" and you will see. If there is no button just refresh your browser.

Comment: when I used this for onkeyup, I cannot type even. So any reason?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const regex = /^\d{1,12}(\.\d{1,2})?$/;
console.log('1234567890123.12', regex.test('1234567890123.12'));
console.log('123456789012.12', regex.test('123456789012.12'));
console.log('123456789012.1', regex.test('123456789012.1'));
console.log('123456789012.', regex.test('123456789012.'));
console.log('123456789012', regex.test('123456789012'));
console.log('12345678901', regex.test('12345678901'));
console.log('1234567890', regex.test('1234567890'));
console.log('123456789', regex.test('123456789'));
console.log('12345678', regex.test('12345678'));
console.log('1', regex.test('1'));
```

Comment: when I used this for onkeyup, I cannot type even. So any reason?